# Efficient ways to find minimum of subset of elements

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find the minimum of each row in a matrix excluding specific elements in those rows.

Specifically in a given row I have precomputed those elements which I want to include given in `valid(i,:)`.

What is the right way to do this, here are the options I've thought of:

```
for i = 1:n
  res(i) = min(x(i, 1, valid(i,:)), [], 3);
  ...
end
```

From what I know about matlab this would be more efficient:

```
res = min(x(:, 1, valid), [], 3);
```

However this will apply only a single filter to the 3rd dimension...

Comment: This is an interesting question, could you provide an example input for this and what would be your expected output?

Comment: How do you define those elements? Your code selects one row, and a specific element from that row, then computes the maximum along the 3rd dimension, which is only a single element... Unless `valid(i)` somehow is something different than a single value. Are you looking for the minimum row, or the minimum within each row? Some example input + output would certainly clarify things.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sorry `valid(i)` was meant to return a matrix (I'm from a more functional programming background...)

Comment: Ah, yes, you can't tell the difference between a function call and a matrix indexing operation in MATLAB. Still, my question about your goal still stands: does "minimum of rows" mean the minimum for each row, or the minimum over all rows. English is also ambiguous at times.

Comment: If the validation conditions change from one row to the next (that's what I understand from valid(i,:), and your comment regarding the fact that the other solution only has a "single" filter), then I think your way of doing things through a for loop is actually the efficient way. You could of course transform this into a vectorized one-liner (e.g. using arrayfun), but you probably would not be gaining any efficiency in the process (any efficiency gains would depend on the sizes of the matrices you will be using in production, let us know if that's relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having played with this for a bit it turns out to be extremely efficient to exploit the way that matlab treats `NaN` values.

Specifically in this case:

```
xp = x;
xp(~valid) = NaN;

res = min(xp,[],3);
```

This has given an approximate conservative speedup of 100x, since the previous version (explicitly looping through) each iteration took ~10s and now 100 iterations take ~5s.

Note: there is an edge case where if there aren't any valid elements then you end up with `NaN` as the result for that row.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) as follows. Not sure if it will be faster than your answer:

```
[~, jj] =  find(valid); % column indices, to be used as grouping variable
res = accumarray(jj, x(valid), [size(x,2) 1], @min, NaN); % NaN used as fill value
```